# Using form to show all records where certain value is greater than X

Tags: php, sql, database

For this problem I need to make a PHP page where the user can search an invoice table by inputting a "quantity" value. The form then takes that quantity and spits out a table with the name, invoice number, quantity, and item description for all invoices where the quantity exceeds the quantity the user submitted.

For the most part I have my page set up and working fine. Where I'm getting stuck is on the query side -- specifically, the code below is providing me a list of invoices where the quantity is identical to the input quantity.

I've tried changing "WHERE ii.quantity LIKE ?" to "WHERE ii.quantity > ?" but all that does is provide me a list of all invoices without filtering by the user submitted quantity.

```
    $query = 
    "SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name, ii.invoice_id, ii.quantity, it.description
     FROM `c2092`.`customer` c
     JOIN `c2092`.`invoice` i ON c.customer_id = i.customer_id
     JOIN `c2092`.`invoice_item` ii ON ii.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
     JOIN `c2092`.`item` it ON it.item_id = ii.item_id
     WHERE ii.quantity LIKE ?
     ORDER BY ii.invoice_id";
```

Comment: What is the type of your quantity property in database ?

Comment: How are you executing it in PHP?

Comment: @Flyzzx Right now it's set as int(5)

Comment: @ChrisWhite Fairly straightforward I believe. $stmt->execute(["%$quantity%"]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too complex query. Try to make explain on it. I am sure it will use filesort, and even temp table.

The better approach is to make several queries:

```
$invoiceItems = $db->query(
"SELECT ii.invoice_id, ii.id, ii.quantity, it.description
 FROM `c2092`.`invoice_item` ii
 JOIN `c2092`.`item` it ON it.item_id = ii.item_id
 WHERE ii.quantity > ?
 ORDER BY ii.invoice_id");

$invoiceItemMap = [];
$invoiceIds = [];
foreach ($invoiceItems as $invoiceItem) {
   $invoiceItemMap[$invoiceItem['invoice_id']][] = $invoiceItem;
   $invoiceIds[$invoiceItem['invoice_id']] = $invoiceItem['invoice_id'];
}
$invoiceIds = array_values($invoiceIds);

$userInvoices = $db->query(
"SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name, i.invoice_id
 FROM `c2092`.`invoice` i
 JOIN `c2092`.`customer` c ON c.customer_id = i.customer_id
 WHERE i.id IN (".implode(',', $invoiceIds).")");

$result = [];
foreach ($userInvoices as $row) {
  $result[] = array_merge($row, $invoiceIds[$row['invoice_id']]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello,

What is the value of your variable?

Prefer the use of named parameter instead of ? syntax.